# "Up until that time" sounds awkward -- is there a better way to say it?

Tags: phrase-requests

Maybe I'm having a bad day, but I've just written a sentence similar to this one, and it doesn't read well for me, but I can't think of anything better right now:

> The task was to build a new accounting system; **up until that time** they had been doing everything by hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good word for this would be *hitherto*.

> The task was to build a new accounting system; hitherto, they had been doing everything by hand.

Comment: This sounds like the right answer to me, though I'm open to being corrected.

Comment: Note, though, that `hitherto` can sound ridiculously old-fashioned and pretentious.

Comment: @grautur Nonsense.

Comment: "Hitherto" is a great word - and we shouldn't treat great words like fine China that we place in the cabinet and never use.

Answer (score 14):

I would use *until then*.
*Until*, in sentences like *the kidnappers have given us until October 11th to deliver the documents* means *up to*.

Looking at the [Corpus of Contemporary English](http://www.americancorpus.org/) to see how much frequently the phrases *until then*, *up until then*, *up until that time*, and *until that time* are used, I get these data (the frequency is given in per million):

[image: first chart]

If I look at when those phrases are used, I get the following data:

[image: second chart]

Comment: Why are the points of "until then" across Spoken/Fiction/etc. connected by lines? They're not showing a progression, are they? :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might say

> ...previously they had been doing everything by hand.

Or if you're trying to highlight an accomplishment on a CV you might say

> ...built a new accounting system which greatly reduced the need to do everything by hand.

Comment: Yes, I thought of previously just after asking the question. Or maybe *before that*. It's not for a CV, but I think you're suggestion of completely rewording it is probably the best.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds grammatical to me, though I would probably go with a simple "up until then", myself. The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org) have the following stats:

```
                    BNC    COCA

up until that time    5      46
up until then        50     123
```

Answer (score 1):

*Hitherto* means *up until now* - from *hither* meaning *here* - as in this current point in time.  More correct, but little used, might be *thitherto*.